# Magento: How to write an extension with a block that overrides functionality and another new custom block?

Tags: php, magento

I was in the middle of writing some code for a Magento website, and I feel like I'm at odds with what I am trying to accomplish.

I am trying to write an extension which inserts 2 blocks:

1. Hello_Catalog_Block_Category_View: which overrides the Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View Block with some extra functionality.
2. Hello_Catalog_Block_Custom: which is a customised class I want to create for this extension

Here's what I have tried to write in the config.xml file:

```
<blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <category_view>Hello_Catalog_Block_Category_View</category_view>
                </rewrite>
                <class>
                     <custom>Hello_Catalog_Block_Custom</custom>
                </class>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
```

Obvously if I tried this code when I refresh the browser, this doesn't work because I must have initialised the custom block the wrong way.

Now if I tried to write in this fashion:

```
<blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <category_view>Hello_Catalog_Block_Category_View</category_view>
                </rewrite>
                <class>Hello_Catalog_Block</class>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
```

Now when I refresh the browser, the templates for Catalog Category view don't get rendered and I get the feeling it gets overridden by `<class>Hello_Catalog_Block</class>`.

My question is, is there a way to write an extension that allows these 2 blocks to be used or together or would it just be a case where either you write an extension that overrides blocks or you write an extension that creates new blocks only, not both?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, Magento now has its own StackExchange site: http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: When you say "Obviously if I tried this code when I refresh the browser, this doesn't work" could you go into more detail?  It's not clear if you mean the rewrite doesn't work, or the custom block doesn't work.  Also, it's not clear how you're testing/determining if the custom block doesn't work.

Comment: @AlanStorm - Sorry I was unclear. I the part that does not work is the custom block not rewrite section. I also have tested this by putting a log call in the newly created classes' constructor method so that I know that the class has been initialised, then refreshing the page in question in the browser. During my tests my logs showed that the class I was using to rewrite the category view block worked fine whilst the custom block never got loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a disconnect between what you think a "custom block" will do and what they actually do.  There's no way to just add something to `config.xml` and have the block show up on the page.

If you want to create a custom block for your module, the first step is to configure a new top level section under blocks

```
<blocks>
    <hello_catalog>
        <class>Hello_Catalog_Block</class>
    </hello_catalog>
</blocks>
```

The `<hello_catalog>` node is you block's group name.  When you use the above configuration, you're telling Magento

> Hey Magento, if you see a block in the `hello_catalog` group, it's class name should start with `Hello_Catalog_Block`.

With the above in place, you'll be able to do things in Magento's layout update XML files (the XML files in `app/design`) like this

```
<block type="hello_catalog/custom" name="me_custom_block" />
```

The above XML is creating a block of type `hello_catalog/custom`.  That's a block in the `hello_catalog` group, with its class name being `custom`.  Magento will translate this into the full class name `Hello_Catalog_Block_Custom` (using the information from `config.xml` for the base name, and then lead-word-casing `custom`.

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation, I think I've got more clarity on how to use these blocks. I thought it was hard to explain at first cause I tried asking another collegue of mine but he was confused as well.